# How to change LogFile.Directory property via WMI on a remote computer?

Tags: iis-7, wmi, get-wmiobject

I was able to retrieve, using WMI, the value of `LogFile.Directory` for a specific IIS site located on a remote computer.
Now I need to change the `LogFile.Directory` property - this is a step in an automation process - but I am hitting a wall. This is what I have so far, although it doesn't work.

```
    Write-Output "Making IIS connection to $($XmlCloudNodeFullyQualifiedDomainName)"
    $site = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $XmlCloudNodeFullyQualifiedDomainName -Namespace "root/webadministration" -Class Site -Authentication 6 -Filter "Name = '$IISSiteName'"
    If ($site.Name -eq $IISSiteName) { 
        Write-Output "Found site $IISSiteName"
        Write-Output ("Existing log folder: " + $site.LogFile.Directory)
        $newLogFolder = "E:\" + $IISSiteName + "\logs"
        Write-Output ("Set IIS log folder to " + $newLogFolder)
        $site.LogFile.Directory = $newLogFolder
        $site.Put()
    }
```

I don't get any errors. Simply the `LogFile.Directory` value does not change on the remote machine when I check in IIS Manager.
I've read that I should be using `Set-WMIInstance` instead, so I tried:

```
    Write-Verbose "Making IIS connection to $($XmlCloudNodeFullyQualifiedDomainName)"
    $site = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $XmlCloudNodeFullyQualifiedDomainName -Namespace "root/webadministration" -Class Site -Authentication 6 -Filter "Name = '$IISSiteName'"
    $sitePath = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $XmlCloudNodeFullyQualifiedDomainName -Namespace "root/webadministration" -Class Site -Authentication 6 -Filter "Name = '$IISSiteName'").__path
    If ($site.Name -eq $IISSiteName) { 
        Write-Output "Found site $IISSiteName"
        $newLogFolder = "E:\" + $IISSiteName + "\logs"
        Write-Output ("Existing log folder: " + $site.LogFile.Directory)
        Set-WmiInstance -Path $sitePath -argument @{LogFile.Directory = $newLogFolder}
        Write-Output ("Set IIS log folder to " + $newLogFolder)
    }
```

But this throws errors:

```
At E:\\Test.ps1:71 char:54
+             Set-WmiInstance -Path $sitePath @{LogFile.Directory = $newLogFolder}
+                                                      ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At E:\\Test.ps1:72 char:18
+             Write-Output ("Set IIS log folder to " + $newLogFolder)
+                  ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At E:\\Test.ps1:41 char:54
+     foreach ($FSMappingNode in $FSMappingNodesArray) {
+                                                      ~
```

Is there a way to change this particular value remotely or is it a read-only property?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

// Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tinkering, I finally found the way to change the `LogFile.Directory` of an IIS site remotely:

```
    Write-Output "Making IIS connection to $($XmlCloudNodeFullyQualifiedDomainName)"
    $site = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $XmlCloudNodeFullyQualifiedDomainName -Namespace "root/webadministration" -Class Site -Authentication 6 -Filter "Name = '$IISSiteName'"
    $sitePath = $site.__path
    Write-Verbose $sitePath
    If ($site.Name -eq $IISSiteName) { 
        Write-Output "Found site $IISSiteName"
        Write-Verbose ("Existing log folder: " + $site.LogFile.Directory)
        $newLogFolder = "E:\" + $IISSiteName + "\logs"
        $siteLogFile = $site.LogFile
        $siteLogFile.Directory = $newLogFolder
        Set-WmiInstance -Path $sitePath -Arguments @{LogFile = $siteLogFile}
        Write-Output ("Set IIS log folder to " + $siteLogFile.Directory)
    }
```